# Copy to clipboard with Javascript in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, clipboard

I really need a way to copy some text to the OS clipboard in Firefox.

Know it is easy in IE and not possible in Chrome and Opera unless flash is used. Because of different reasons I am unable to use the flash solution!

Had it working in the past but now the netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege is protected as far as I can figure out (since ver. 17).

It looks as if it is still possible according to this article:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_the_Clipboard

Believe it is still necessary to enable the possibility in the user.js file like this

```
user_pref("capability.policy.policynames", "allowclipboard");
user_pref("capability.policy.allowclipboard.sites", "http://");
user_pref("capability.policy.allowclipboard.Clipboard.cutcopy", "allAccess");
```

But how shall I do it? Have made some test without great success and think there is no guide on the web that explain how it shall be done in a generic way. E.g. a simple guide about how to enable javascript access to the clipboard. Hopefully also a guide that can be used by the novice user. Like to do it and post it here but need a working solution first.

According to the web there are 2 solutions for copy to clipboard;

```
document.execCommand("copy", false, null)
```

and

```
var gClipboardHelper = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/widget/clipboardhelper;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIClipboardHelper);
  gClipboardHelper.copyString("Put me on the clipboard, please.");
```

Both generate a failure with my first try.

The solution below need the user to press CTRL+C and I need a solution where the text shall copy based on the press of a button (many on a single page).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344325/copy-to-clipboard-on-firefox-and-google-chrome/11346026#11346026

My old solution was like this:

```
var clip = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/widget/clipboard;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIClipboard);

if(clip)
{
  var trans = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/widget/transferable;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsITransferable);

  if(trans)
  {
    var str = new Object();
    var len = new Object();
    var str = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/supports-string;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsISupportsString);

    if(str)
    {
      var clipid=Components.interfaces.nsIClipboard;

      if(clipid)
      {                 
        str.data = cliptext;

        trans.addDataFlavor('text/unicode');                    
        trans.setTransferData("text/unicode", str, cliptext.length*2);      

        clip.setData(trans, null, clipid.kGlobalClipboard); // No return value
        return 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Components.classes is undefined in unprivileged code (not add-on etc) so I do not believe any solution with this will work any more. One option is to make an add-on that will execute in privileged code area and send the text that shall be copied to this add-on for it to handle the copy to the OS clipboard (nice new possible project).

This only leave document.execCommand("copy", false, null) in the field as a stand alone solution.

Tried this code and it does not copy anything to the OS clipboard - but do not generate any errors btw.

```
var pre = document.getElementById('pcryptcopytext');

if(!pre)
{
  pre = document.createElement("pre");
  pre.setAttribute('id', 'pcryptcopytext');
  pre.setAttribute('style', 'opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: -10000px; right: 0;');
  document.body.appendChild(pre);
}

pre.innerHTML = cliptext;
pre.contentEditable = true;
//pre.unselectable = "off";
//pre.focus();

if (document.createRange) 
{
  var rng = document.createRange();
  rng.selectNodeContents(pre);
  document.execCommand("copy", false, null);
  document.body.removeChild(pre);
}
```

So, anybody got a working solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by creating a Firefox Add-on that exposes the clipboard object: https://github.com/myplaceonline/myplaceonline_ffclipboard

Example:

```
if (window.ffclipboard) {
  window.ffclipboard.setText("clipboard text");
}
```

Comment: The add-on can be installed into Firefox from Mozilla.org by going here:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ffclipboard/
It does not require a restart.
Flash-based solutions like zeroclipboard require the user to click on the hidden flash movie, so if you have a complex UI requirement, implementation is difficult.  With this solution, you can just call the two lines of code when the user clicks on anything.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like this is not supported any more, and there is no replacement :(

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/977068#answer-500083

Maybe making some noise in a Firefox bug will help us get a (safe) solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for that link. I spend some time trying obsolete solutions until I found your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use firefox `navigator` object

```js
navigator.clipboard.writeText("text you want to copy").then(() => {
    // on success
}, (e) => {
    // on error
});
document.execCommand("copy");
```

Comment: Sadly, firefox doesn't support .write(), which can be used to write HTML to the clipboard

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with the copy action being initiated by a user action, such as a button click, then according to [MDN's "Interact with the clipboard" documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard#using_execcommand), no special permissions are needed.

---

You create a button, for example:

```
<button id="myCopyBtn">Copy to Clipboard</button>
```

Then the copy-to-clipboard function to be executed upon a user click:

```
function copyToClipboardFn() {
    let copyText = "This text will be copied to clipboard";
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText);
}
```

Finally, assign our function to the button as a click event handler:

```
document.querySelector("#myCopyBtn").addEventListener("click", copyToClipboardFn);
```