# Copy to the Clipboard using jQuery in FireFox

Tags: jquery

How do I copy text to the clipboard using a text link in Firefox?

I know how to do it in IE and Chrome but that solution does not work in Firefox.

Comment: For security reasons you can't access it. See duplicate question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21696052/copy-to-clipboard-with-javascript-in-firefox

Comment: Did you even try researching this?

Comment: Yes I did but no relevant sourcecode in relation to FF